# Should I check if array is null in a react selector

Tags: reactjs

**Story**

I am working on a react application with a state redux.
In that state, there is an array called 'students', initialized as empty. This array is updated through calls to HTTP rest services.

I have also created a selector to pick the data that I need.

student.reducer.ts :

```
    const initialState = {
    students: []
    }
```

student.selector.ts :

```
export const studentsFullName = (students) => {

  return students.map(
    student => ({
      id: student.id,
      fullName:
        `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
    })
  );
};
```

**Question**

Considering that the rest service should NOT return a null object for the students, should I, **in the selector**, add a condition to return an empty array if 'students' is null, or is it useless ?

student.selector.ts :

```
export const studentsFullName = (students) => {

  // is this necessary ?
  if (!students){
    return [];
  }

  return students.map(
    student => ({
      id: student.id,
      fullName:
        `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: If something can go wrong, it will go wrong. So you can do `(students || []).map()`

Comment: Thank you, I am using your solution @ZohaibIjaz

Answer (score 0):

You can have a check like

```
export const studentsFullName = (students) => {

  return {student.length && students.map(
    student => ({
      id: student.id,
      fullName:
        `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
    })
  );
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies. Finally, I used @Zohaib [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995877/should-i-check-if-array-is-null-in-a-react-selector#comment107912256_60995877), which is

```js
(students || []).map(
    student => ({
      id: student.id,
      fullName:
        `${student.firstName} ${student.lastName}`
    })
  );
```